# Input lose focus, React React-hooks Axios

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks, axios

Everything works great, but after every type in the search field, I think all page are re-rendered, and input loses focus.

P.S `fsac = FilmsSeriesAnimeCartoons`, I create an abstract component to render these 4 models, maybe someone knows a better way to do this than passing value to props

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

```
const FsacList = (props) => {
    
        const BASE_URL = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${props.fsac}`;
    
        const now = new Date().getUTCFullYear();
        const years = Array(now - (now - 73)).fill('').map((v, idx) => now - idx);
    
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
        const [data, setData] = useState([]);
        const [genres, setGenres] = useState([]);
        const [params, setParams] = useState({
            page: '1',
            ordering: '-created',
            search: '',
            year: '',
            genre__name: '',
        });
    
        useEffect(() => {
            const fetch = async () => {
                setLoading(true);
                try {
                    const getGenres = axios.get(`${BASE_URL}-genres/`);
                    const getData = axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/`, {params});
                    const responses = await axios.all([getData, getGenres]);
                    setData(responses[0].data);
                    setGenres(responses[1].data);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error.message);
                }
                setLoading(false);
            }
    
            fetch();
        }, [props.fsac, BASE_URL, params]);
    
        function genreClick(e, genre) {
            if (params.genre__name === genre) {
                setParams(prev => ({...prev, genre__name: ''}))
            } else {
                setParams(prev => ({...prev, genre__name: genre}))
            }
        }
    
        function yearClick(e, year) {
            if (params.year === year) {
                setParams(prev => ({...prev, year: ''}))
            } else {
                setParams(prev => ({...prev, year: year}))
            }
        }
    
        function sortClick(e, field) {
            if (params.ordering !== field) {
                setParams(prev => ({...prev, ordering: field}))
            }
            if (params.ordering === field) {
                setParams(prev => ({...prev, ordering: `-${field}`}))
            }
        }
    
        const SeacrhComponent = ({search, setParams}) => (
            <input type="text"
                   placeholder={"Search"}
                   onChange={e => setParams(prev => ({...prev, search: `${e.target.value}`}))}
                   value={search}
            />
        )
    
        return (
            <>
                {loading && <Spinner/>}
                {!loading && (
                    <div>
                        <SeacrhComponent search={params.search} setParams={setParams}/>
                        <ul>
                            {genres.map(genre =>
                                <li key={genre.id}>
                                    <button onClick={(e) => genreClick(e, genre.name)}>
                                        {genre.name}</button>
                                </li>
                            )}
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {years.map(year =>
                                <li key={year}>
                                    <button onClick={(e) => yearClick(e, year)}>
                                        {year}</button>
                                </li>
                            )}
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <button onClick={(e) => sortClick(e, 'title')}>Title</button>
                                <button onClick={(e) => sortClick(e, 'year')}>Year</button>
                                <button onClick={(e) => sortClick(e, 'rating')}>Rating</button>
                                <button onClick={(e) => sortClick(e, 'created')}>Date</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {data.results.map(item =>
                                <li key={item.id}>
                                    <p>{item.title}</p>
                                    <p>{item.year}</p>
                                    <p>{item.desc}</p>
                                    <p>{item.rating}</p>
                                </li>
                            )}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                )}
            </>
        )
    }
    
    export default FsacList;
```

Comment: can you add your SeachComponent also

Comment: Please define your component `SeacrhComponent` outside `FsacList`, otherwise, it will recreate in every re-render and you will lose focus.  Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72847369/losing-focus-on-input-onchange-react/72847534

Answer (score 0):

You need to create SeacrhComponent outside of your FsacList component like below

```
const SeacrhComponent = ({search, setParams}) => (
            <input type="text"
                   placeholder={"Search"}
                   onChange={e => setParams(prev => ({...prev, search: `${e.target.value}`}))}
                   value={search}
            />
        )
const FsacList = (props) => {...}
```

EDIT: explaining why we need to place search component outside FsacList component:
The reason your input was loosing focus was that when you were typing inside the input the onChange Method was calling setParams method which was re-rendering the FsacList component, on Re rendering the Search Component was re created. When we move the Search component outside FsacList, it will be re render but will be created once.

EDIT:
Added a Codesandbox demo:
[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-sid-hmhyb9?file=/src/FsacList.js:3423-3431)

Note I have commented axios call as I do not have the server running but I do not think that will affect the solution, please check out the demo.

Comment: @Bvavesh Daswani                                                                                                                       i did what you said but it didn't help, also i rebuild and restart app

Comment: I have created a Code sandbox demo, please have a look of that.

Comment: @Bvavesh Daswani, yes it works great, so the problem with axios call?