# Losing focus on input onChange React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

What I'm trying to achieve, it's to create each input as own component.
And I can't get how to fix thing when my app all the time rerendering when I'm pressing any key.
I know if I'll use controlledInputs -> so each input would have it own useState that would work. But the main idea to do that this way

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const ControlledInputs = () => {
  
  const [person, setPerson] = useState({ firstName: '', email: '', age: '' });
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setPerson({ ...person, [name]: value });
  };
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (person.firstName && person.email && person.age) {
      const newPerson = { ...person, id: new Date().getTime().toString() };
      setPeople([...people, newPerson]);
      setPerson({ firstName: '', email: '', age: '' });
    }
  };
   function FormControl({number, idname , type , text}){
    return(
      <div className='form-control'>
        <label htmlFor={idname}>{text} : </label>
        <input
          type={type}
          id={idname}
          name={idname}
          value={person[idname]}
          onChange={(e) =>handleChange(e)}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
 
  return (
    <>
      <article className='form'>
        <form>
          <FormControl idname={"firstName"} type={"text"} text={"First name"}/>
          <FormControl type={"email"} idname={"email"} text={"Email"}/>
          <FormControl type={"age"} idname={"age"} text={"Age"}/>
          <button type='submit' className='btn' onClick={handleSubmit}>
            add person
          </button>
        </form>
      </article>
      <article>
        {people.map((person) => {
          const { id, firstName, email, age } = person;
          return (
            <div key={id} className='item'>
              <h4>{firstName}</h4>
              <p>{email}</p>
              <p>{age}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </article>
    </>
  );
};

export default ControlledInputs;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the `FormControl` outside of `ControlledInputs`, otherwise, React will recreate it and you lose focus as well as data.

And you need to pass `value` and `handleChange` as props in `FormControl`.

Here are codes you can refactor. Please note that the `number` you defined is not removed.

```
function FormControl({value, handleChange, idname , type , text}){
  return(
    <div className='form-control'>
      <label htmlFor={idname}>{text} : </label>
      <input
        type={type}
        id={idname}
        name={idname}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) =>handleChange(e)}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Usage in `form`:

```
function FormControl({value, handleChange, idname , type , text}){
  return(
    <div className='form-control'>
      <label htmlFor={idname}>{text} : </label>
      <input
        type={type}
        id={idname}
        name={idname}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) =>handleChange(e)}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

const ControlledInputs = () => {
  
  const [person, setPerson] = useState({ firstName: '', email: '', age: '' });
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setPerson({ ...person, [name]: value });
  };
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (person.firstName && person.email && person.age) {
      const newPerson = { ...person, id: new Date().getTime().toString() };
      setPeople([...people, newPerson]);
      setPerson({ firstName: '', email: '', age: '' });
    }
  };
   
 
  return (
    <>
      <article className='form'>
        <form>
          <FormControl idname={"firstName"} type={"text"} text={"First name"} value={person['firstName']} handleChange={handleChange}/>
          <FormControl type={"email"} idname={"email"} text={"Email"} value={person['email']} handleChange={handleChange}/>
          <FormControl type={"age"} idname={"age"} text={"Age"} value={person['age']} handleChange={handleChange}/>
          <button type='submit' className='btn' onClick={handleSubmit}>
            add person
          </button>
        </form>
      </article>
      <article>
        {people.map((person) => {
          const { id, firstName, email, age } = person;
          return (
            <div key={id} className='item'>
              <h4>{firstName}</h4>
              <p>{email}</p>
              <p>{age}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </article>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `FormControl` is defined inside the `ControlledInputs` component. So, on each rerender of the `ControlledInputs`, you create a new `FormControl` function and that means that React will treat it as a different component than the one in the previous render, and so it will lose focus, as the old one is considered unmounted.

Just define the `FormControl` outside the other one, and pass it what extra data you need as props, and you should be set.

Comment: That's sound like a good plan.
But how can I access for example function from main component (in our case handleChange()), if child component would be out of it.

Comment: @НикитаЛямный You can pass it as a prop.